# Retrieving information from semi-related entities in Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Ι have a "Product" table which holds the general information about a product:

```
id  
name  
price
```

I also have a "ProductViewCount" table which holds the number of views for each product, with a new count being started at the beginning of each day:

```
id  
product_id  
date  
count
```

How would I construct the entities in a way that would allow me to search for a product then access the count for that product on any given day (if it exists)?

Comment: one to many? your product have many counts and your count is only for one product. is this what you are asking for ?

Comment: It is, but I'm having trouble understanding how I'd access a count for a certain date through the Product entity.

Comment: you can get the count entities from your product `$product->getCounts();` and then use method `FindByDate();` on your counts entities. `$count= $countRepo->findOneBy(array('product' => $product, 'date' => $date);` also you can do something like this, its the better way becouse its better scalability. you will find a count for specified date and product

Comment: Currently I'm getting the list of products in the controller and then iterating through them in the twig template to display their information. If I wanted to show today's count for each product, does that mean I'd have to iterate through each product in the controller, making another query to find today's count and adding that onto an array? Or is there a more logical way of doing it?

Comment: the second option is the best one, cous you query only one object from db and doing like you said what if there is 100000... queries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to @Vardius's answer (happy for them to have the accepted answer), define the relationship to the ProductViewCount entity as a one to many from Product to ProductViewCount with an ArrayCollection instance in your Product entity.

Then, add a method to your Product entity, lets say the ArrayCollection was named "viewCounts":

```
public function addViewCount(ProductViewCount $viewCount)
{
    $this->viewCounts->add($viewCount);
}
```

Then, from your controller where $countRepo is a reference to your ProductViewCountRepository, $products is the Product entities you just fetched from your ProductRepository and $date is the date to query for:

```
$counts = $countRepo->findBy(array('product' => $products, 'date' => $date));
if ($counts) {
    foreach ($counts as $count) {
        $products[$count->getProductId()]->addViewCount($count);
    }
}
```

You can then arrange how you'd like in the view layer.